# Invoking Parent JavaScript from IFRAME IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

All I want to do is invoke a JavaScript function on the iframes parent.
This is also on the same domain.

If I create a button to trigger the parent from the frame:

```
<script>
        function onClick() {
            parent.hidePrintButton();
        }
</script>
<button id="test" onclick="onClick();">Call Parent Window Function</button>
```

It works as intended in all Browsers.

However when I have an ajax call that performs the :

```
parent.hidePrintButton();
```

The parent does not get called in IE but does in every other browser.

I then get the error :

> Object doesn't support property or method 'hidePrintButton'

This looks like the when I interact with the page, the parent works but not when it has been run in the iframe onload.

I have tried postmessage, event listeners, bind, parent. and none of these seem to be able to run the JavaScript on the parent page.

I though this might be related to when the button is pressed down and focus is on the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was unable to fix the issue on IE11 only.

The only way around this is to create a method to poll the iframe till it comes back with the response that you are looking for:

```
var keepPolling = true;
function pollFrame() {
   if ($("#refFrame")[0].contentWindow.processed){
      setProcessed();
      keepPolling = false;
   }
   if(keepPolling) {
      setTimeout(pollFrame, 750);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use window.parent isntead of just parent:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534326(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have also tested this to no avail.